# How to include kernel headers in a program

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, header-files

I am writing a libnetfilter_queue program. I am new to linux kernel programming. I need to include linux/skbuff.h,
net/checksum.h and many related kernel headers which are not present in /usr/include/linux. I get following error on compilation

```
 fatal error: linux/skbuff.h: No such file or directory
 fatal error: net/checksum.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I guess if you installed them, a -I/usr/include/linux should work... How did you installed your kernel's headers?

Comment: i use ubuntu 12.04, the following package is already installed linux-headers-3.2.0-32

Comment: You probably only need the kernel headers if you are compiling a kernel module; in that case your module & kernel specific makefile should deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `find / -name skbuff.h 2>/dev/null` then when it finds the location use the `-I/path/to/folder` when you compile your program.. If it doesn't find the header you don't have it!

Comment: find /usr [...] should be enough ^^

Comment: I added the path /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-32/include/ but i get following error : /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-32/include/linux/bitops.h:22:24: fatal error: asm/bitops.h: No such file or directory

Comment: do you know how to add a directory to your path?

Comment: g++ -Wall -I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-32/include/ -o filter -lnetfilter_queue

Comment: thats a no, type $PATH in terminal copy paste that then go to your home directory and type `vi .bashrc` add  what your copied and add your desired directory to include it in the search path see if that works for example `PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-32/include/:$HOME/bin`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the locate DB, `locate linux/skbuff.h`.